# Index match multiple criteria vba to create userform

Tags: vba, match, lookup, userform

I am trying to create a data entry tool for a spreadsheet with over 150 tabs.  Each tab, or sheet, has the same layout, and represents a different company.  Data will be entered into column C, or D, based on two variables: **Type**, or **Item**, values obtained from two combobox inputs. The tab, or company, is found by a listbox.

I want to use *Index-Match* to return the row number as input for the cells method, to enter the data. I have searched several sites, including here. The difference with my code is I am trying to use nested functions and combobox values for assignments. Here is my code: (includes step for selecting relevant tab)

```
Private Sub EnterCommandButton_Click()
'Activate relevant sheet and go to first tab via Goto function call
'Double check Sheets property regarding name and listbox values
Application.Goto Sheets("MgrListBox.Value").Range("$C$6:$F$93")

'Transfer Information
Cells(WorksheetFunction.Row(Index("C6:F93", Match(1,("C6:C93" = _
   TypeComboBox.value)*("D6:D93" = ItemsComboBox.value),0),3),5).Value = _
   LongTextBox.Value

Cells(WorksheetFunction.Row(Index("C6:F93", Match(1,("C6:C93" = _
   TypeComboBox.value)*("D6:D93" = ItemsComboBox.value),0),3),6).Value =
   ShortTextBox.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question outright but I can't get it to fit in the comments.
Your code has many issues.

**First**, you don't need `Goto` to access your sheet.
**Second**, using `WorksheetFunction` is different from assigning or writing a formula on a cell.
 You use valid range or array objects/variables within your sub to execute it and not the string address equivalent of it.
So this line:

```
Cells(WorksheetFunction.Row(Index("C6:F93", Match(1,("C6:C93" = _
   TypeComboBox.value)*("D6:D93" = ItemsComboBox.value),0),3),5).Value = _
   LongTextBox.Value
```

will throw an error. Also I am not sure if it can store array values the same way as when you enter it in a cell.
 You can try using `Evaluate Function` like this though:

```
Cells(WorksheetFunction.Row(Evaluate("Index(C6:F93, Match(1,(C6:C93 = " & _
   TypeComboBox.value & ")*(D6:D93 = " & ItemsComboBox.value & "),0),3)"), _
   5).Value = LongTextBox.Value
```

`Evaluate` will treat the string formula as it would a normal formula in a cell.
It will work considering the logic behind your formula is correct and will return a number.
Again, I'm not sure if this will help you in anyway but I hope it does.

Comment: I believe the evaluate statement is helping. Any suggestion on a better way to navigate to the relvant tabs, selected in a listbox?

Comment: @AlexB123 Of course, but please clarify what you are trying to do. If you can put a simple illustration of your data and the expected result that would be great.

Comment: thanks for your help. My tool uses the MgrListBox.Value to choose the correct tab. Then Type and ItemsCombobox take my two criteria.  I want to use the combobox's to return a row reference.  The issue is there aren't any headers, and I don't want to change the workbook.  Based off of reference, I want to use the Cells property to identify where input from tool will land. Suppose the following data:                                                         a c 1                                                                   a d 2
    b c 3
    b d 4